# How to stop JavaScriptCore JSContext evaluating by force on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, javascriptcore

Sometime the script being evaluated should be stopped by force, but I can't find a way to achieve this. Someone pointed out `JSContextGroupSetExecutionTimeLimit` might work, but It doesn't in my testing, can anyone help?

Another reference: https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS/issues/14

My code:

```c
int extendTerminateCallbackCalled = 0;
static bool extendTerminateCallback(JSContextRef ctx, void *context)
{
    extendTerminateCallbackCalled++;
    if (extendTerminateCallbackCalled == 2) {
        JSContextGroupRef contextGroup = JSContextGetGroup(ctx);
        JSContextGroupSetExecutionTimeLimit(contextGroup, .200f, extendTerminateCallback, 0);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

+ (void)stop
{
    JSGlobalContextRef ref = [_context JSGlobalContextRef];
    JSContextGroupRef contextGroup = JSContextGetGroup(ref);
    JSContextGroupSetExecutionTimeLimit(contextGroup, .200f, extendTerminateCallback, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea of possible approach

```
+ (void)stop
{
     JSContext *context = [JSContext currentContext]; // or whichever your

     // set property of JS global object to specific know value
     // that should be checked inside JS code regularly during
     // long operations and interrupt self execution
     context[@"externallyCancelled"] = @(YES); 
}
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer and should be accepted. The most reliable way is probably just to set a flag and then add code to exit early from the JS, as shown in the example.